# Is there any other method to set background image to take less memory

Tags: ipad

When I set the background image of a UIView with

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mainScreenBackground" ofType:@"png"]]]];
```

it takes 6 mb of memory.
I want another way that takes less memory.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use a UIImageView?

Comment: hi do u want to reduce the size of image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

Does this work??